# What is the Modules and Plugins and what i should use?

Tags: c#, plugins, module

I intend to develop a system that is entirely based on modules. The system base should have support for finding out about plugins, starting them up and being able to provide ways for those modules to communicate. Ideally, one should be able to put in new modules and yank out unused modules at will, and modules should be able to use each other's functionality if it is available.

i will build my application in c#, i have googled about this and i find: 
- Microsoft Prism it is a Modular base Pattern? if it is, please if there are an other mechanism or pattern i want to know.
- Is there an OSGI for C# like in java? 
thanks before.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar using MEF ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx